# RenderScript - call to clamp() is ambiguous

Tags: android-renderscript, clamp

In my `RenderScript` file, I have the following:

```
out.b = clamp(out.b, 0, 255);
```

When I build the project, I get the following error:

```
error: call to 'clamp' is ambiguous
```

Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it probably doesn’t know the types of the inputs. Use an explicit cast for the constants to match all the types.

If out.b is uchar:
`out.b = clamp(out.b, (uchar)0, (uchar)255)`